# AngularJS: ng-click doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I built a function that counts how many times the user clicked on his name in the users table, but the ng-click doesn't triggers the function.

HTML code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in Users.slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage), ((currentPage)*itemsPerPage))">
     <td class="col-lg-1" ng-click="tapName(user.userName)">{{user.userName}}</td>
     <td class="col-lg-1">{{user.PassWord}}</td>
     <td class="col-lg-1">{{user.Name}}</td>
     <td class="col-lg-1">{{user.LastName}}</td>
     <td class="col-lg-1">{{$index}}</td>
     <td class="col-lg-1">{{user.countConnect}}</td>
     <td class="col-lg-1">{{user.countPaging}}</td>
     <td class="col-lg-1">{{user.countOrder}}</td>
     <td class="col-lg-1">{{user.countTapName}}</td>
</tr>
```

AngularJS function code:

```
$scope.tapName = function(name){
    if($scope.User == name){
        $scope.User.countTapName ++;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `User` in the scope. The scope contains `Users`, which is an array of users. You should not pass the user name as argument. You should pass the user itself:

```
ng-click="tapName(user)"

$scope.tapName = function(user){
    user.countTapName++;
};
```